# Login details are not valid

Tags: authentication, laravel-8

if i enter my user_email and user_pass it says Login details are not valid even tho its the right user_email and user_pass stored in my database table (wp_users). i dont know whats wrong with my code

i tried this

```
function loginPost(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'user_email' =>  'required',
        'user_pass'  =>  'required'  
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('user_email', 'user_pass');
    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        return redirect()->intended(route('home'));
    }
        return redirect(route('login'))->with('error', 'Login details are not valid');
}
```

and im expecting that if i try to login with my right user_email and user_pass it will direct me on my home route. but even tho my credentials are correct, it still says Login details are not valid.

Comment: You have to double-check everything, so `dd($credentials);`, open the attempt function and dd all the sub functions. It might be as simple as WordPress encrypting the passwords in a different way than Laravel